JavaFX MediaPlayer.setRate() doesn't work after MediaPlayer.pause();
Playing an .mp4 video in JavaFX MediaPlayer.
Here is pseudo-code
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("myVideo.mp4"));
...
player.play();          // the rate is 1
player.setRate(2);      // the rate is 2
player.pause();         // the rate is 2
player.play();          // the rate is 2, but the player plays the media at rate 1.

How to continue playing video at speed 2 (fourth line) after pausing the video?
My environment is Mac OS, Java 22, Javafx 24-ea-15.

I cannot reproduce the problem on Windows 10 with Java 23.0.1 and JavaFX 23.0.1 (or 24-ea+15).
